# Xilinx Virtex 6 FPGA - how to read memory

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am new to FPGAs. I would like to learn how I should go about reading the memory (DDR3) of the Xilinx Virtex-6 FPGA ML605 kit.

I would also like to learn how to write simple schematics to the FPGA. I have so far only managed to write logic programs using the ISE Project Navigator.

Comment: Just FYI:  Nobody uses schematics for FPGA logic design.  Certainly not for anything even remotely complex.  I shouldn't say "nobody".  New people do, and people who don't know what they are doing.  Everyone else uses VHDL or Verilog.  It is in your best interest to learn one of those.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the DDR memory on the board, you must use a memory controller. There are some good tutorials that can help you with that such as:

- [Memory Interface Solutions User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/ise_tutorial_ug695.pdf)

And

- [ISE In-Depth Tutorial](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/ise_tutorial_ug695.pdf)

And one that is specifically useful for you is the

- [ML605 Reference Design User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug535.pdf)

You can find the files for ML605 on Xilinx's special page:

http://www.xilinx.com/products/boards/ml605/reference_designs.htm

these are last updated for ISE 13.2 and may need some work updating it to the latest version of ISE.